# Java: program to replace characters in text file

Tags: java, text, edit

In the first line that begins with ">", I want the program to swap the "|" with "\t", then add a "\t" to the end of that line. On the remainder, I want the program to delete the "\n" until it reaches another ">" character.
Another way of saying this: I want the first line just to swap characters, but as long as the line does not contain a ">" character, I want to delete the "\n" characters.

Hopefully you can help me because this code does not remove the "\n" characters for some reason.
This is what I have written so far:
Thanks!!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

public class Nov18{
    public static void main( String args[] ){
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "BIOIhonorsproject" ));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "BIOIfinaldata" ));

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine () ) != null){
                if (line.startsWith( ">")) { line = line.replace ( '|' , '\t');
                     line += "\t";

                     while ((line = br.readLine () ) != null){ 
                         line = line.replace ("(\\n)", ""); 
                     }
                }
                bw.write( line);
            }
            br.close();
            bw.close();
        }
        catch( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println( "error" );
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry this is so difficult to explain. I want the first line just to swap characters, but as long as the line does not contain a ">" character, I want to delete the "\n" characters.

Comment: The `replace` method is looking for a sequence of characters that matches `(\\n)` and replacing it with an empty string. You might be looking for `replaceAll` instead - either that or change `(\\n)` to `\n`.

Comment: "I want the program to delete the "\n" until it reaches another ">" character" - does this second ">" also appear at the start of the line?

Comment: The text file currently looks like this:           >klaj |sdflk |iwoeroi |jsdmckljd | oijfeijaskdjf \n   klajsdflkiwoeroijsdmckljdoijfeijaskdjf \n klajsdflkiwoeroijsdmckljdoijfeijaskdjf \n      AND I want it to look like this:    >klaj \t sdflk \t iwoeroi \t jsdmckljd \t oijfeijaskdjf \n   klajsdflkiwoeroijsdmckljdoijfeijaskdjfklajsdflkiwoeroijsdmckljdijfeijaskdjf

Comment: Sorry this is so difficult to explain. I want the first line just to swap characters, but as long as the line does not contain a ">" character, I want to delete the "\n" characters.

Comment: @Lauren: Instead of adding all this as comments, please edit your answer. The easier you make it to understand the problem, the more likely you will get answers.

Comment: Hi Lauren.  It looks like you are missing a bw.write(line); command (before your second "while" statement for example.  Where you have "line += "\t";  you need to write out line after that, otherwise the very next "while" statement overwrites the line var.  Hope that helps.